# Short Time Fourier Transform in C#

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft

I'm writing the following code that implements the stft (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) through the Exocortex library          (http://www.exocortex.org/dsp/), where "window" is a 512 Hamming window, "left" is the left channel from an audio stream passed into a double array, "frames" is the number of frames I split the audio file into (say around 600) and the "offset" variable performs the overlap.
I've also added the ability of zero padding in the Exocortex FFT class:

```
     if( data.Length < length ) {
            for (int k = data.Length; k < length; k++)
            {
                data[k].Re = 0;
                data[k].Im = 0;
            }
```

The problem is that for frames=600 this code runs for about 7000msec! Am I missing something here?

```
     Exocortex.DSP.ComplexF[] x_frame = new Exocortex.DSP.ComplexF[2048];

        int offset = 0;
      for (int m = 0; m < frames-1; m++)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
            {
                x_frame[i].Re = (float)(left[i + offset] * window[i]); 
                x_frame[i].Im = 0;
            }
            Exocortex.DSP.Fourier.FFT(x_frame, 2048, FourierDirection.Forward);


            offset += 256;
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you're filling 599 values for a 2048 sample FFT ?

Comment: I fill the first 512 values in the inner loop for x_frame, as i goes from 0 to 511. Then, because 512<2048, I zero-pad the rest values, so I get a 2048 length FFT.

Comment: Can you run it after commenting out the fft and see how long it takes to just perform the windowing and formating the data?  600 2048 point ffts should be much faster than 7 sec.

Comment: It took 3 msecs ( or about 6800 ticks if you want)... I just can't see what I'm missing here :/